# Adding SSL to my Amazon AMI EC2 instance

Tags: linux, webserver, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I was following this how-to: https://nouveauframework.org/blog/installing-letsencrypts-free-ssl-amazon-linux/

and it leverages *LetsEncrypt* so i was happy to use it.  I was entering this command and was getting error on the script.

Command:

```
certbot-auto --debut -v --server https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory certonly -d mywebsite.com
```

It says it is creating the virtual environment but then fails.

```
/usr/local/bin/certbot-auto: line 679: virtualenv: command not found
```

I am not sure what that means.  Maybe I am doing something wrong, but i dont really know what.

According to `uname -a` I am:

```
Linux www.mywebsite.com 2.6.35.14-95.38.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 25 17:11:23 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Right now when i run the certbot-auto script, it checks that all the packages are the correct version so nothing else is installed.

Is there something wrong with Amazon AMI EC2 instance servers that prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem using certbot on Amazon Linux.  After logging into a server I use it on, I can confirm virtualenv is in fact installed.  Can you try:

```
yum install virtualenv -y
```

Comment: Ill give this a look and see if this would resolve it.